# TypeError returned by fetch API in Chrome iOS 58

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome

I am attempting to use fetch to make an HTTP request. It is working perfectly except on a single iPhone (iOS v10.3.1) and only in Chrome (v58.0.3029.83).

Originally, when we first saw this problem it was because we had header values that were undefined. I have since filtered those headers out, so the only header in the request is:

`Content-Type: application/json`

The response we get is no headers and a body of `TypeError: Type error`. It is not actually making the request as they are not reaching the server.

I am at a loss as to what to do next. Difficult to debug when I don't have access to any devtools for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people seeing this now, I was able to fix the problem by adding a legitimately signed cert to https. Before I was using https with self-signed certs because it was a staging environment and I didn't care about it being legit